# Model using inheritance: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to typemod without a default;

Tags: python, django, database, inheritance, models

I am using model inheritance in my models.py. This is my code:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    stuff = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True,
                             null=True, default="")
class TypeMod(Email):
    pass
```

When I run makemigrations, I get the following message although I have set the default value for all of my fields in the Email model:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to typemod without a 
default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate 
existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows 
with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Please read that very carefully. There's no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out! For anyone who has the same issue, I am using vagrant and this project is running on a vm.So the problem was that the parent model was not abstract before, so a table was made in the database for the parent model. So when I switched to abstract, the table was still there. The way I solved it was that I ran "vagrant distroy" and restarted the vm.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily have to do with vagrant. I used a native Linux machine and got the same message. My solution was to remove the existing migrations.